# Getting error under "Deno.readFile Method()"

Tags: deno

I'm learning `Deno` I'm a beginner, inside **get.js** I got this error [image: get.js']], Anyone please explain What went wrong here? I got an error message and i got an error message under `response` and `Deno`. I provide all the coding below, please anyone help me!

**This is my Console Output**

```
D:\Deno Documentation\deno4>deno run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-write .\index.js
http:/localhost:3000
NotFound: The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:43:11)
    at Object.sendAsync ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:98:10)
    at async Object.open ($deno$/files.ts:37:15)
    at async Object.readFile ($deno$/read_file.ts:13:16)
    at async default (file:///D:/Deno%20Documentation/deno4/controllers/todos/get.js:9:20)
    at async Application.#handleRequest (https://deno.land/x/oak@v4.0.0/application.ts:187:9)
```

**My output in website**
[image: output]

> index.js

```
import {Application} from 'https://deno.land/x/oak@v4.0.0/mod.ts';

import {PORT} from './config.js';

import router from './router.js';

const app=new Application();

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

console.log(`http:/localhost:${PORT}`);

await app.listen({port: PORT});
```

> router.js

```
import {Router} from 'https://deno.land/x/oak@v4.0.0/mod.ts';
import getTodos from './controllers/todos/get.js';

const router=new Router();

router.get('/',({response})=>
{
    response.body="This API is Working";
});

router.get('/todos',getTodos);

export default router;
```

> config.js

```
export const PORT=3000;
export const FILE_PATH='./data/todos.json';
```

> **get.js**

```
import {FILE_PATH} from '../../config.js';

export default async({ response })=>
{

    const decoder=new TextDecoder();

    try {
        const data=await Deno.readFile(FILE_PATH);
        const todos=JSON.parse(decoder.decode(data));

        console.log(data);

        response.status=200;
        response.body={status: 'success',todos};

    } catch (error) {
        response.status=500;
        response.body={status: 'failed',todos:[]};
    }
}
```

> todos.json

```
[
    {"id":1,"title":"title 1","completed":true},
    {"id":2,"title":"title 2","completed":false},
    {"id":3,"title":"title 3","completed":true}
]
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Show the stack trace please

Comment: Actually, inside **get.js** catch part working because of that I see failed message

Comment: What error message?, show it otherwise we can't help you :)

Comment: I uploaded my error message

Comment: Put a `console.log(error)` inside the `catch` and show us the output. That's how we can help you, we need the stack trace :), but most likely you have a JSON error

Comment: I uploaded console error messages

Comment: You're passing an invalid path to `Deno.readFile`, what path are you passing? Are you sure it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update after stack trace was submitted:

The error is telling you that the file does not exist. Provide a valid filepath to `Deno.readFile`

### old answer

The file you're reading from does not contain a valid JSON, most likely since you haven't added a `TODO` yet.

Before calling `JSON.parse` you have to check that `data` is not empty. Or you can add a `try/catch` around `JSON.parse` and default to empty todos.

```js
export default async ({ response }) => {
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();

  try {
    const data = await Deno.readFile(FILE_PATH);
    let todos = [];
    try {
        todos = JSON.parse(decoder.decode(data));
    } catch(e) {
        // invalid JSON, most likely empty file
    }

    console.log(data);

    response.status = 200;
    response.body = { status: "success", todos };
  } catch (error) {
    response.status = 500;
    response.body = { status: "failed", todos: [] };
  }
};
```